# should I write header to all my html page?

Tags: html

I'm new to web design. I wonder that should I have to write header for every page on my website? for example I have index.html, contact.html, about.html. should I copy header to all page ?

Comment: Yes. However, if you don't want to do that for every file you would generally use a server-side language like PHP to put your header in a file then include it on other files so you wouldn't have to keep writing it.

Comment: Yes, you should. it's pretty common practice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each page must contain a header. Because they're separated.

To be honest, these kind of questions (like yours) shouldn't be asked here. You should try to read some HTML books to get you started.